# C# MVC 5 View Should Only Show A Modal If Validation Passes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a C# MVC 5 application that uses Bootstrap. I have a view where the user can fill in some input boxes and confirm entry with a button. It's pretty straight forward stuff.
Anyway, depending on whether the user interaction is an edit or an addition, I show a modal asking them if they like to proceed to the following page that relies on data from the page that they're on.

I.e.
If it's an edit, confirm button posts and sends user back to previous page.
If it's an add, confirm button shows modal dialog asking if they'd like to proceed to adding other stuff which directs the user to another page or sends them to previous page.

I have the following:

```
<button type="button" id="button_submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#questionModal" data-property-one="@Model.Property1" data-property-two="@Model.Property2">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Accept
  </button>
```

Which uses the following jquery

```
$('#questionModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
      var modal = $(this);

      // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modelProperty1 = button.data('property-one');
      var modelProperty2 = button.data('property-two');

      // Update the modal's content.
      modal.find('#something').val(modelProperty1);
      modal.find('#somethingElse').val(modelProperty2);
    });
```

I don't want the question modal to be displayed if required fields are empty.
I have validation in place on all required input fields and a nice warning is shown after a post back to the server. What I need is to be able to do some poor-man's client-side validation and if a required field is not filled-in, post back to the server, ModelState will be invalid which will just return the same view and display error messages and not show this question modal.

Something like

```
@if (@Model.Property1 != null && @Model.Property2 != null)
{
  <button type="button" id="button_submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#questionModal" data-property-one="@Model.Property1 " data-property-two=@Model.Property2">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Accept
  </button> 
}
else @*post back to controller, reconstruct view, and show errors*@
{
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Accept
  </button>
}
```

or perhaps go to a JavaScript function on button click and do something like this instead:

```
function stuff()
{
  var modelProperty1 = //get @Model.Property1 as it is on client somehow
  var modelProperty1 = //get @Model.Property2 as it is on client somehow

  if (!modelProperty1 || !modelProperty2)//if validation fails
  {
    $("form").submit();//post and refresh showing errors
  }
  else
  {
    //set modal properties
    var modal = $('#questionModal');
    modal.find('#something').val(modelProperty1);
    modal.find('#somethingElse').val(modelProperty2);
    //show modal
    modal.modal('show');
  }
}
```

But I'm unsure as to how to get the current values of the input fields as they are client-side.
E.g. var modelProperty1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.Property1)); is null even when the user has typed something into its input box...

I'm not extremely experienced but I'm learning so I hope I'm not appearing to come across silly with these questions.

Thanks so much for you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could role your own JS validation or use a library (almost always recommended) such as http://formvalidation.io.

You can't get the values of @Model.Property directly, as that is server side. You need to get them from an element on the page on the client side. You can use jQuery val() as you have done on the model: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Something like:

```
var modelProperty1 = $("#Property1").val();
```

Not sure if I am missing something. If you don't have Property1 as a form element somewhere you could write it to a hidden field using

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property1)
```

Comment: Ah, you're a star! As those property fields are displayed in @Html.TextBoxFor fields, I can access their client-side values using $("#Property1").val();